# How to align a set of equations with padding?

Tags: equations, align, amsmath, alignment

I have a group of equations that I'd like to align at the `=` sign, but I also want the part before `=` to be left-aligned.

I'm attaching a screenshot of what I want (achieved by manually adding `\qquad` spaces)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand*\xor{\oplus}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
  c_1\qquad &= m_1 \xor k\\
  c_2\qquad &= m_2 \xor k\\
  c_1 \xor c_2 &= m_1\xor k\xor k\xor m_2 = m_1\xor m_2
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

While there are various ways this might be accomplished, if it occurs rarely, just adding an appropriate `\phantom` might be easiest.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand*\xor{\oplus}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
  c_1\phantom{{}\xor c_2 } &= m_1 \xor k\\
  c_2\phantom{{}\xor c_2 } &= m_2 \xor k\\
  c_1 \xor c_2 &= m_1\xor k\xor k\xor m_2 = m_1\xor m_2
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If I would have to use the construct often, I might set up for a TABstack where the phantom would not be necessary, as long as each equation did not require its own number.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,tabstackengine}
\TABstackMath
\TABbinary
\setstackgap{L}{1.2\normalbaselineskip}
\newcommand*\xor{\oplus}
\begin{document}
\[
 \tabbedCenterstack[l]{
  c_1 &= m_1 \xor k\\
  c_2 &= m_2 \xor k\\
  c_1 \xor c_2 &= m_1\xor k\xor k\xor m_2 = m_1\xor m_2
}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 13):

With `alignat`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{alignat*}{3}
  & c_1           &{} = {}& m_1 \oplus k\\
  & c_2           &{} = {}& m_2 \oplus k\\
  & c_1\oplus c_2 &{} = {}& m_1\oplus k\oplus k\oplus m_2 = m_1\oplus m_2
\end{alignat*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: But many answers have you put? ahahah. What do I must voted up :-)?

Comment: @Sebastiano, thank you to point me to my superficiality ... Superfluous one is now deleted

Comment: No no Zarko, I not like your comment. I do many mistakes every day....You not are superficiality!

Answer (score 8):

With `alignat` you can produce pairs of right-aligned/left-aligned columns and no default spacing between them.

The left-aligned columns will produce a correct spacing if starting with a relation symbol.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand*\xor{\oplus}

\begin{document}
\begin{alignat*}{2}
& c_1          &&= m_1 \xor k \\
& c_2          &&= m_2 \xor k \\
& c_1 \xor c_2 &&= m_1 \xor k \xor k \xor m_2 = m_1 \xor m_2
\end{alignat*}

\begin{align*}
c_1          &= m_1 \xor k \\
c_2          &= m_2 \xor k \\
c_1 \xor c_2 &= m_1 \xor k \xor k \xor m_2 = m_1 \xor m_2
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

I added also a more common rendering.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Here are two other approaches using `\mathmakebox` (mathtools) instead of `\phantom`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\newcommand*\xor{\oplus}

\newlength{\wdmax}
\newsavebox{\maxbox}

\begin{document}
\settowidth{\wdmax}{$\displaystyle c_1 \xor c_2$}%
\begin{align*}
  \mathmakebox[\wdmax][l]{c_1} &= m_1 \xor k\\
  \mathmakebox[\wdmax][l]{c_2} &= m_2 \xor k\\
  c_1 \xor c_2 &= m_1\xor k\xor k\xor m_2 = m_1\xor m_2
\end{align*}

\savebox{\maxbox}{$\displaystyle c_1 \xor c_2$}%
\begin{align*}
  \mathmakebox[\wd\maxbox][l]{c_1} &= m_1 \xor k\\
  \mathmakebox[\wd\maxbox][l]{c_2} &= m_2 \xor k\\
  \usebox\maxbox &= m_1\xor k\xor k\xor m_2 = m_1\xor m_2
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use an array to accomplish what you want. And if you want the equation to have a number, just replace the $$[...]$$ by \begin{equation}[...]\end{equation}. To change the alignment of any column, just change the 'l' to 'r' or 'c' in the arguments of the array.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\newcommand*\xor{\oplus}

$$
\begin{array}{ll}
  c_1\qquad &= m_1 \xor k\\
  c_2\qquad &= m_2 \xor k\\
  c_1 \xor c_2 &= m_1\xor k\xor k\xor m_2 = m_1\xor m_2
\end{array}
$$
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TSE. With LaTeX, it's better to use `\[...\]` rather than `$$...$$`.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Unfortunately the spacing isn't correct. You get something better by using `{l@{\;}l}` as array specification; and note that while `mathtools` is a recommended package to type serious math, it is not really relevant for this answer.